# What does S in linux file properties mean?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm creating directories and changing the permissions of them in perl with the following code:

```
umask 0000;
mkdir $path, 0770;
chown $userid, $groupid, $path;
```

Now when I do ls -l on a directory I've just created, they are as follows:

```
drwxrws---  2 user group 4096 Nov  3 15:34 test1
```

I notice for the group permissions, there's an s instead of x.
Even if I chmod manually to remove all permissions for the user and group ("chmod g=" and "chmod u=", it's still there:

```
d-----S---  2 user group 4096 Nov  3 15:36 test2
```

The internet suggests S means everything in the folder is run as su or something? I don't quite understand what it means but I figure I should understand seeing as these are webroots so if there's a security implication, I ought to be aware of it.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not a programming question, thus it is off-topic.

Comment: I did wonder. Which site do you suggest it should go instead? I was thinking serverfault but then I figure it's not really a sysadmin question either

Comment: [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Look at the footer - all non-beta sites are listed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s` means the `setgid`/`setuid` bit and the `executable` bit both are set

`S` means only the `setgid`/`setuid` bit is set

check out `man chmod` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the `umask` value you're setting.

> The internet suggests S means everything in the folder is run as su or something?

That is incorrect.

If the `setuid` bit is set on an executable program, then it will execute with the privileges of its owner.

If the `setgid` bit is set on the executable program, then it will execute with the permissions of its group.

So, don't go around creating things as `root:root` with `umask 0000`.

Better yet, don't ever set that to your umask.

See here: http://linuxzoo.net/page/sec_umask.html

> The number given as a parameter to the umask command works in a opposite manner to the number given to the chmod command. The 'mask' serves to remove permissions as opposed to granting them.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, it indicates an "error":

There is no point in setting the setuid bit, if the executable bit is not set.